# Emacs Python Virtualenv Support

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-mode

I am able to enable a virtual environment by adding these lines in `.dir-locals.el` in my project directory:

```lisp
((python-mode . ((python-shell-virtualenv-root . "s:/.virtualenvs/default/"))))
```

Now `M-x run-python` runs a Python interpreter from that specified virtual environment.

My question is, how can I open a shell or run a shell command like `pip install numpy` from that virtual environment?

I am aware that there is a pyenv.el package. The built-in Python.el must have this functionality.